# Refresh from Server in Mavensmate, not refreshing correct data

Tags: mavensmate

When I right click on some metadata in Mavensmate, and I say "Refresh from server", all the metadata dissapears and only header level remains. I am testing with refreshing a profile. If I refresh at the Project level, it refreshes correctly.

[image: Mavensmate Metadata]

Comment: Issue listed on GitHub https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/390

Comment: Did you find a solution, I having a similar issue, random files just dissapear and i only gets the xml's

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have subscribed to "Profile" under MavensMate --> Settings --> User.
If "Profile" is not included, add them Mavensmate --> Project --> Edit Project --> Project Metadata and try again.

[image]

Comment: Profile is already there.